# Git pull duplicate files

Tags: git

I have a large repository of over 1.2Gb. Two folders are full with textures taking up 1Gb, all of the other files are just code. So I thought I could add the two texture folders, next git init that folder, and then git pull the rest of the files. However it wont recognize the two textures folders resulting in duplicate files which cancel the process.
Is there a way I can pull all other files with git recognizing the other two folders?

Comment: Seems, that solution, mentioned there http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/124764 is suitable for your needs.

Comment: Keep it simple and make two separate repositories, then include one in the other with submodule or subtree or manually copying.